# Me and my wife only need Legal divorce papers but by mouth don't want to say neither she want

Tags: sunni, talaq

Me and my wife only need Legal divorce papers but by mouth don't want to say neither she wants. our purpose is to require only divorce certificate for settling in some other country and we want to show as bechlors.

In this case, the divorce will be valid or we will remain in Nikkah. **Please note we don't want actual divorce. We only need a paper.**

Please advise.

Regards,
SH

Comment: So you want to create fake papers, lie, get involved in fraud, and probably in some other unlawful activities (for which you are doing this), and don't see anything wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

To divorce someone Islamically you need to say the word طالق (you are divorced) out loud. If you plan to divorce someone just by making an intention then the divorce won't happen.

As for what you mentioned in your question, this is not permissible in islam. You can't fake anything unless there is an urgent necessity (e.g. death or prosecution).